# prompt user to select a filename

Tags: python, csv

How can I change the code below to prompt the user for the column number and csv filename instead of stating it in the code?

```
#!/bin/env python

col = 2

values = []
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv:
for line in csv.readlines():
    elements = line.strip().split(',')
    values.append(int(elements[col]))

csum = sum(values)
cavg = sum(values)/len(values)
print("Sum of column %d: %f" % (col, csum))
print("Avg of column %d: %f" % (col, cavg))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`input()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

```
filename = input('Please enter a filename: ')
col = int(input('Please pick a column number: '))
with open(filename, 'r') as csv:
```

or you could accept a command-line argument; [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) gives you a list of command-line parameters, where index `0` is the script name, and anything beyond that are values the user put on the command line:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Please specify a filename and column number: {} [csvfile] [col]'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

filename = sys.argv[1]
col = int(sys.argv[2])
```

The Python standard library includes a [`argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to make handling command line interfaces more flexible and powerful.